# Android drawable sizes

Tags: android, image, size, drawable, dimension

Hi I have a question about different types of drawable assets.
I know there are mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi... and so on.
What I usually do is to create an icon, I create a big one (like 144x144) and put it in xxhdpi only. So if the device is mdpi or hdpi, the icon will be shrinked automatically and it looks okay to me.
I am wondering if this is a normal way if want to use the same image for all these types.
If I want to use different images based on dpi, of course I will have to create images for mdpi, hdpi and so on.. but if I want to support only one image then is it considered okay? Are there any drawbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if there wasn't any drawbacks then it wouldn't be introduced to use images of different densities. When you use a **larger image (144x144)** and it doesn't actually shrink itself for lower density device. As there are many types of devices available on the market. Some ar big but have lower density (for example tablets of low prices) some devices are small but has very high density. So in these special cases your single image is not enough to maintain the similarity.

There are some really awesome tools available that simple generates all images for all the required densities within a single click.

You can check http://makeappicon.com/

You just need to put a single image it will create all the necessary densities.